# Why was my question closed as opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

My [question about edge computing](https://serverfault.com/questions/1150338/how-does-edge-computing-actually-work) was closed as opinion-based.

Here is the relevant help page:

> **Opinion-based** - Discussions focused on diverse opinions can be great, but they just don't fit our format well.
>
> > This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.
>
> It’s often possible to rewrite opinion-based questions to focus on a more fact-based line of questioning. If you see a way to do this, consider editing the question.

I don't see, how this applies to my question. I am not asking for personal opinions, I am interested in purely factual information about the real world implementation details of this approach to internet infrastructure.

If my question is actually opinion-based, please explain how so.

If it is not, I would like to know if the question can be reopened.

Comment: IDK why Opinion based was chosen, You ask 13 separate questions,  I would have gone for lacks focus (or whatever it's called today). Also with that many questions, there is plenty of research you could have done but failed to demonstrate. In the grand scheme of things the correct thing happened - your poor/bad/crappy question got closed and the internet is better for that.

Comment: @user9517 The "13 questions" are mostly rhetorical and are meant to refine what part of the main question in the title I need help with. If I removed these clarifying questions and kept only the question in the title, it would be almost certainly closes as "too broad" or that it "Needs details or clarity". Also, the first paragraph of the question indicates, that I tried searching all of the relevant search terms that I could come up with, but was not able to find any concrete information. If my research attempts succeeded, I wouldn't be asking my "crappy question" now would I?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed the close reason to better reflect the question's issues.

Comment: I have tried to reword my question a bit, to make it more focused. I am assuming, that the problem was with the open ended nature of the question rather than the number of question marks (since most of these sub-questions were just clarifying/rhetorical rather than totally separate questions).

Answer (score 0):

`where exactly does the "cloud" begin and end isn't really clear to me.`

That isn't answerable due to the "cloud" and "edge" are colloquial. They are intended to apply familiar and somewhat similar terms to what otherwise are abstract definitions.

When phrase words that were intended to help instead becomes the bright shiny object that precipitates a dozen questions, it failed and perhaps other words should be substituted, but that isn't the purpose of this forum.

Comment: I understand that these terms may have colloquial/marketing uses, however they are also used by professionals, in technical contexts (web dev, dev ops, networking, etc). Just cause the terms are a bit abstract doesn't mean that you can't define them and reason about them. Computers are like 99% abstraction anyway